# Is Toggle Terminal Ctrl + ` , removed from VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I updated vs code and was trying to use Ctrl + ` ,to toggle terminal visibility.

It seems to does not work anymore.I don't do any custom keybinding. How do I do reset defaults for all the settings in vs-code? This is weird I updated vscode recently that's it.

Comment: which key is mapped to command **View: Toggle Terminal**

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. 2) What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)?